# Error: 'Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int ' on date type

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a table with `date` data type column in SQL Server.

I want to select records that have `ExpireDate >= Datetime.Now`

I use a stored procedure.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Ad_SelectByCommand]
@Where varchar(max),
@SQLSort varchar(max)
AS
DECLARE @query varchar(max);

    IF @Where <> N'' SET @Where = N' WHERE ' + @Where
    IF @SQLSort <> N'' SET @SQLSort = N' ORDER BY ' + @SQLSort

SET @query = 'SELECT [Id], [Name], [Description], [Image], [ExpireDate], [Cost], [IsPayment] FROM [dbo].[Ad]' + @Where + @SQLSort

EXEC(@query)
```

and use it in C#:

```
var list = clsAdFactory.GetAllByCommand("ExpireDate>=" + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString());
```

and

```
var list = clsAdFactory.GetAllByCommand("ExpireDate>=" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
```

but I get error

> Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int

Comment: When i use this , i get error `Invalid column name 'yyyy'.
Invalid column name 'MM'.
Invalid column name 'dd'.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap the date in quotes:

```
string whereClause = string.Format(@"ExpireDate >= '{0}'", DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString());
var list = clsAdFactory.GetAllByCommand(whereClause);
```

Comment: Prefer `string.Format` to concatenation as it usually makes stuff easier to read +1 on that

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
var list = clsAdFactory.GetAllByCommand("ExpireDate>='" + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()) + "'";
```

You final SQL is something like this:

```
WHERE ExpireDate>=20140101
```

When it should be more like this:

```
WHERE ExpireDate>='20140101'
```

You might even need a few extra single quotes to keep it happy:

```
var list = clsAdFactory.GetAllByCommand("ExpireDate>=''" + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()) + "''";
```

Comment: Thanks, when i use this final sql is `ExpireDate>=''02/05/2014''` and get error `Incorrect syntax near '02'.`